# Using GROUP BY together with wildcards for table columns

Tags: postgresql, group-by

**Issue**

Is possible insert substitution for all cols of joined table? For example like this.

```
select distinct
p.product_id,
i.filename,
pl.* -- instead of pl.price_tax, pl.price_rec, etc.

from
s_product p
left join s_product_image i on i.product_id = p.product_id
left join s_pricelist_generated_lists pl on pl.product_id = p.product_id
```

Using Postgres 11.5

**Edit**

First error. Why?

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "pl.product_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Ok, then I added to `group by` this.

```
group by
p.product_id,
i.filename,
pl.*
```

But it does not take in this syntax.

> SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "pl.product_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Here is the whole sql (`pl` changed to `pp`).

```
select distinct
        p.product_id,
        i.filename,
        pp.*
from s_product p
  left join s_product_image i on i.product_id = p.product_id
  left join s_pricelist_generated_lists pp on pp.product_id = p.product_id
group by p.product_id,
         i.filename,
         pp.*
order by p.product_id
```

Error:

> SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "pp.product_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: That syntax is valid - which you can easily find out by running that query

Comment: Some DBMSs (or some ancient versions) require for asterisk-fieldpattern to be at the beginning of output fieldset, before any separate field and/or expression. But AFAIK PostgreSQL do not require that.

Comment: @all See my update please. Thanks.

Comment: While using GROUP BY clause you have no way to use asterisk in it. But you may use asterisk in output fields list for some table if all fields from this table are listed in GROUP BY expression separately. PS. *First error* - not matched the above query.

Comment: Note that the `psql` version is usually irrelevant. The more important information is the version of the server - you can see that using `select version();`

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort (all of words you've typed here and time spent) to avoid typing out a column name...

Comment: See modelling [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=877563bf532d67c177ba7f4f07bafe1b).

Comment: @all Ok, so I can't use `*` in `group by`, so I need to insert all cols to `group by` from table `s_pricelist_generated_lists` one by one, right? But there is quite a lot of cols... :/

Comment: *so I need to insert all cols to group by from table s_pricelist_generated_lists one by one, right?* True. *But there is quite a lot of cols...* Don't be lazy...

Comment: PS. If you include all fields from some table, and nevertheless have duplicates which needs to be distincted/grouped - your DB is not normalized, and the table have no primary/unique keys at all. It is more than bad...

Comment: The query seems useless. Please answer: What is the problem if you remove both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ~ 60000 records instead ~20000, many duplicates by id which are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use GROUP BY with wildcards if you include primary keys into GROUP BY list. Added in 9.1 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html#AEN110817.

Answer (score 0):

> select distinct
> p.product_id, i.filename, pp.*

"select distinct" is a Big Red Flag for me.

`select distinct a, b, c`
can perform as badly as
`select a, b, c group by a, b, c order by a, b, c`!

It requires your database to retrieve all the requested data, including all the "duplicates" that you might be getting and then to go through and remove all those duplicates.
The more columns you "distinct", the more work the database has to do.

Far, *far* better to *avoid* the duplicates in the first place, many of which are introduced by poor join conditions.

In you case, it may be better to use a subquery to extract the product_id of each record you're interested in, then join to that result to get the individual record details.